# Automatically update a LOG table when there is a change in db from controller/model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using Laravel 4.2. I have been asked in an interview that How can we be able to insert the data into a database table, when we are using CRUD Operations from Laravel controller/model etc.

I have previously achieved this in a way that before sending data to the controller, I update the model like...

```
Log::insert($data)
```

In this way there is additional work in every controller.
Can we use `App::bind` thing while implementing this?

Comment: @Epodax Stack Overflow *is* a free coding service, within reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a [Model Event](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#model-events)

```
Model::saved(function($user)
{
    Log::insert($data)
});
```

You might also want to check out this tutorial [Using Laravel 4's Model Events](https://driesvints.com/blog/using-laravel-4-model-events)